# show that $\det{(A^2+B^2+C^2-BA-CB-AC)}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B,C\in M_{2}(C)$ such that
$$A^2+B^2+C^2=AB+BC+CA$$

show that

$$\det{(A^2+B^2+C^2-BA-CB-AC)}=0$$

from:[matrix indentity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7h1062330_matrix_and_determinant)

Comment: Use the determinant product formula $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$.

Comment: @YourAdHere  I don't know he can use this formula

Answer (score 3):

**Hint :**
if $A\in M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ then :
$$\det(A)=(tr(A)^2-tr(A^2))/2,$$
and we know that $$tr(A^2+B^2+C^2-BA-CB-AC)=tr(AB+BC+CA-BA-CB-AC)=0$$